# Checking for incorrect input inside properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties, error-handling

I am using properties to allow a single string `name` to be added to the class `Details`, I want the property to only accept the string if it can be split into two parts.

The two parts would be the `firstName` and the `LastName`. However if the resulting split has 1,0 or more than 2 strings in the array then the input should be deemed invalid and I want to throw a error to whatever code called the property in the first place.

Can error handling be done on properties like this?

If **not** then what of the following is the preferred way to get data into a class whilst checking for correctness:

1. Use a method inside the class `Details` to handle error inputs, make that method `boolean`.
2. Continue using properties but have the error checking done by the code that calls the property. I don't like this because I want all the error checking code to be self-contained in the `Details` class.

.

```
class Details
{
    private string firstName, lastName;

    public string Name
    {
        // name
        get { return firstName + " " + lastName; }
        set 
        { 
            string name = value;
            string[] nameArray = name.Split(' ');
            firstName = nameArray[0];
            lastName = nameArray[1];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am mostly interested in what of the three options is concidered best pratice:

1. Error check inside properties.
2. Error check outside class in another class, and then just add the verified inputs to `Details`
3. Use a `boolean` method inside `Details` to verify the inputs.

Comment: you can check the length of array inside the property.

Comment: @RajasekarGunasekaran, Is that good coding though? It seems from a few answers below that it is not a good idea to do any checking inside a property.

Comment: @Joseph There's nothing wrong with validating input inside a property setter.  In fact, it's a very common, even standard, practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add my perspective to what others have said, it seems to me that part of the difficulty stems from the fact that you're using a property setter to do something non-trivial (split a string, validate the results, and then store the results in two fields).  Generally, properties, especially read/write properties, should only be concerned with getting and setting a single value (using read-only properties to return a simple computed value is common enough too).

If it were me, I'd have separate properties for the first name and last name, with a third computed property for the full name:

```
class Details
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
      get { return string.Concat(this.FirstName, " ", this.LastName); }
    }
}
```

Then you could add a method to set the full name.  A method is more appropriate than a property setter for this task, since it's non-trivial and has more potential for problems:

```
public void SetFullName(string fullName)
{
  string[] nameComponents = fullName.split(' ');

  if (nameComponents.Length != 2) 
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("The full name must contain a first and last name.");
  }

  this.FirstName = nameComponents[0];
  this.LastName = nameComponents[1];
}
```

I also want to give a plug for the [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx) package.  It may be more complication than you're looking for here, but it's a great way of validating input and output in your applications.

Answer (score 2):

I would follow an existing validation framework, such as [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

Also, in your specific case, I would have a SetName(string fullName) method that does the parsing and populating.

Comment: Thanks, so properties shouldn't really be used for parsing and validating data? This is not considered good coding?

Comment: I consider properties as simple passthrough with minimal functionality. You should feel safe to databind to properties and not have performance concerns.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This makes sense now and does clear things up. From what you have said and also Jetti, validating inside a property is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use exception to capture the error condition.

```
    private string firstName, lastName;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return string.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName); }
        set
        {
            string name = value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Name"); }

            var nameParts = name.Trim().Split(' ');
            if (nameParts.Length != 2) { throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name value"); }

            firstName = nameParts[0];
            lastName = nameParts[1];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I wouldn't consider data that doesn't meet business logic an exception and thus wouldn't throw one. What I would do is this:

```
class Details
{
    private string firstName, lastName;

    public string Name
    {
        // name
        get { return firstName + " " + lastName; }
        set 
        { 
            string name = value;
            string[] nameArray = name.Split(' ');
            if(nameArray.Length == 2) 
            {
                firstName = nameArray[0];
                lastName = nameArray[1];
            } 
            else
            {
                firstName = nameArray[0]; 
                lastName = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
         return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName);
    }
}
```

You can then use the name property and then check to see if the name is valid. If not valid, then you can take the appropriate action.

<strike>Another option would be to have the validation done in the method calling Details.Name.</strike>

EDIT: want to remove what I think is bad advice but keeping so comments make sense, so just striking them out

EDIT2:

You could also do something like this:

class Details
    {
        private string firstName, lastName;

```
    public string Name
    {

        get { return firstName + " " + lastName; }
        private set;
    }

    public bool TryParseName(string name)
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        string[] nameParts = name.split(' ');
        if(nameParts.Length == 2) 
        {
             firstName = nameParts[0];
             lastName = nameParts[1];
        }
        else
        {
             isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Where you would do

```
if(details.TryParseName(name))
{
    // is valid name
}
else
{
    // handle invalid name
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jetti, If I have the validation done in the method calling `Details.Name` that method could easily reside inside `Details`. Is that correct? This way the entire class is self contained.

Comment: @Joseph I have modified my answer. I don't think that verifying outside the class would be a good idea. You could, however, create another method that would take a string and then double check to ensure it is properly formatted and then have it return bool. I'll add an example

Comment: @Jetti Why do you consider invalid input not to be an exceptional condition?  Seems like a typical `ArgumentException` scenario to me.

Comment: @JeremyTodd I understand some would use an `ArgumentException' but it is something that can be handle quite easily by using if statements. To me, it isn't exceptional behavior if it is expected to happen.

Comment: @Jetti See, I feel the opposite way.  I wouldn't consider input that would cause normal execution of the method body to fail and/or put the object into an invalid state to be expected behavior.  It can be handled by `if` statements, sure, but those `if` statements should be executed by the caller to make sure the input is valid before invoking the setter.